# during combination of JSX and HTML giving [object Object]

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make an app which if app finds  **a** and any letter **e** has to give yellow box. for ex:

**name** ===> **n[yellow box]m** // lets assume this [yellow box] is real yellow box

**game** ===> **g[yellow box]m**

the code below instead of showing me [yellow box] its [object Object] . how to fix it?

```
 yellowMaker = word => {
  {var newWord = Array.from(word).map((char, index, arr) => {
      if(char == 'a' && arr[index+2] == 'e') {
        return <div className="box yellow"></div>;
      } else if(char == 'e' && arr[index-2] == 'a') {
        return '';
      } else {
        return char;
      }
    }).join('');
    return newWord}
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.box {
  float: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  clear: both;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.result {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: `return <div className="box yellow"></div>;` returns an object, not a string, unlike the other two `return`s in your `map` function. When you `join('')`, JavaScript calls `toString()` on that object and you get `[object Object]`.

Comment: do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Return a string, not an object. `return '<div class="box yellow"></div>';`

Comment: this is what giving me with your code, when I put word "game" ====> g<div class="box yellow"></div>m

Comment: Well, it's a comment, not an answer. Kind of expecting a lot for free, huh? :). I think you can figure out how to get HTML into React; it shouldn't be terribly difficult. Something about `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Answer (score 1):

try returning the html like this

```
yellowMaker = word => {
  {var newWord = Array.from(word).map((char, index, arr) => {
      if(char == 'a' && arr[index+2] == 'e') {
        return <div className="box yellow"></div>;
      } else if(char == 'e' && arr[index-2] == 'a') {
        return '';
      } else {
        return char;
      }
    }).join('');
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: newWord}}></div> }
}
```

Comment: it is still giving me [object Object]. thank you so much for your trying